# Customize the appearance of a date range on a Calendar control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I have an ASP.NET `Calendar` control on my web form.

I have defined a date  range with a `StartDate` and an `EndDate` and now I need to make all the days in between (including the `StartDate` and `EndDate`) red.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the [`Calendar.DayRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) event and customize the appearance of the cells within your date range. A complete example is on the MSDN documentation page, but the most important part is:

```
Sub DayRender(source As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs)
    ' Change the background color of the days in the month to yellow.
    If Not e.Day.IsOtherMonth And Not e.Day.IsWeekend Then
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
    End If 
End Sub 'DayRender
```

You just need to adapt the `If` to compare the day to your custom range and change the background color from yellow to red.